# What does continuity at a point mean in the context of various kinds of points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

Suppose $f$ is a real-valued function whose domain is the *closed* set $E$ where $E = [-2, -1] \cup \{1, 0, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, \dots\}\cup [2, +\infty)$. Suppose $f$ is continuous on $E$. Note that $\{1, 0, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, \dots\} = \{\frac{n}{n+1}: n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}\} \cup \{1\}$.

I recently read that continuity is defined at points (as opposed to sets) in real analysis and I am trying to understand what that means.

Notice that $1$ is a limit point of $E$. Can the value of $f(1)$ without changing any the value of $f$ at any other point be changed such that $f$ remains continuous on $E$?

**My work on this**:

> Suppose, as an example,  $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x) = 5$. Since $1$ is a limit point of $E$, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ s.t. $0<|x-1|< \delta \implies |f(x)-5|< \epsilon$. Now, I think that we can change the value of $f(1)$ to something that is at least as close to $f(x)$ as $5$. Suppose $4$ is such a point. So, let $\epsilon >0$ and suppose $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$. Then, $|f(x)-4|\le |f(x)-5|< \epsilon$. On the pther hand, this could also be related to the following theorem:

> If $p$ is a limit point of $E$, $f$ is continuous at $p$ $\iff$ $\lim _{x\to p} f(x) = f(p)$

Is my work correct?

Also, notice that $0$ is an isolated point of $E$. Can the value of $f(0)$ without changing any the value of $f$ at any other point be changed such that $f$ remains continuous on $E$?

**My idea:**

> I know that since $0$ is an isolated point, then $f$ has to be continuous at $0$. So, I am guessing that we can change the value of $f(0)$ and still have that $f$ is continuous on $E$.

Is this correct?

What about $-1$? Can the value of $f(-1)$ without changing any the value of $f$ at any other point be changed such that $f$ remains continuous on $E$?

**My idea:** I am a little lost on this one. How can $f$ be continuous at $-1$? Does the right-hand side limit at $x=1$ even exist? Does this have something to do with vacuous truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous on $E$, and $1$ is a limit point of $E$, changing the value of $f$ only at the point $1$ will make $f$ discontinuous at $1$. The sequence $\left\langle\frac{n}{n+1}:n\ge 1\right\rangle$ converges to $1$, so in order for $f$ to be continuous at $1$, the sequence $\left\langle f\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right):n\ge 1\right\rangle$ of function values must converge to $f(1)$, and they will no longer do so if you change $f(1)$.

In your example, for instance, for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that

$$\left|f\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)-5\right|<\epsilon$$

whenever $n\ge n_0$. If you take $\epsilon=\frac12$, then

$$\left|f\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)-4\right|>\frac12$$

whenever $n\ge n_0$, and $f(x)$ clearly does not approach $4$ as $x$ approaches $1$ in $E$.

You are correct, however, in thinking that you can change the value of $f$ at an isolated point without losing continuity of $f$.

Intuitively, the idea is that if $f$ is continuous at some point $a$ that is a limit point of the domain of $f$, then the value of $f(a)$ is completely determined by the values of $f$ at points near $a$. *Near* is an ill-defined concept here, which is why we have the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, but this is still a useful intuition. It gives you an idea of why you lose continuity when you change the value at a limit point, which has points near it, but not when you change the value at an isolated point, which does not.

$-1$ is a limit point of $E$, not an isolated point, so changing $f(-1)$ **will** make $f$ discontinuous at $-1$. Continuity of $f$ at $-1$ means that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(-1)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-(-1)|<\delta$ **and** $x\in E$, and since $-1$ is a limit point of $E$ only from the left, this simply means that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(-1)|<\epsilon$ whenever $-1-\delta<x\le -1$ (since we can always choose $\delta\le 1$, so that $-1-\delta<x\le -1$ ensures that $x\in E$).

Answer (score 0):

Give $E$ the subspace topology. $f:E\to \mathbb R$ is continuous at $x=1$ if and only if for all sequences $(x_n)\subseteq E$, one has $x_n\to x\Rightarrow f(x_n)\to f(x)$. Now, if $x=1,$ there is only one such sequence in $E$ that satisfies the condition, that is, $\frac{n}{n+1}\to 1$ and so $f(\frac{n}{n+1})\to f(1)$ so if $f(1)\neq \underset{n\to\infty}\lim f(\frac{n}{n+1})$, then $f$ cannot be continuous. Since limits are unique, it follows that $f$ must be defined as $\underset{n\to\infty}\lim f(\frac{n}{n+1})$ in order that it be continuous.

On the other hand, if $x\in E$ is isolated, then $\{x\}$ is open in $E$ so there is no sequence (in $E$) that converges to it. It follows that every sequence that converges to $x$ in $E$ (there are none) will satisfy $x_n\to x\Rightarrow f(x_n)\to f(x)$ no matter what value for $f$ at $x$ is chosen. So, in this case, $f$ may be defined any way you want.